# API flow from Client to Backend in case backend is a URL

Tags: java, rest, api, web-services, apigee

I am learning APIGEE. We are being taught configuration of API proxy considering a backend(https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cdcatalog.xml). I imagined backend to be physical servers. 
Can someone please explain how the flow works when the backend is a URL and if there are any physical servers in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your backend service has a URL, it must definitely be residing on a physical server with a host name and port number. You will have to configure the target endpoint in Apigee proxy flow accordingly.

Comment: should be a comment